# PLSQL - Update statement with variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am currently trying to write an update statement using a variable (which will be expanded to use multiple variables later on).

Currently I have the following statement (altered for posting here), but I am running into an error and I don't immediately see the mistake I am making:

```
DECLARE 
v_var1 table1.CY_VALUE % TYPE;
BEGIN

SELECT SUM(Column1 + Column2) 
INTO v_var1
FROM table2
WHERE survey_ID = 1 AND Active_Flag = 1
GROUP BY SURVEY_ID;

UPDATE table1
SET CY_VALUE = v_var1
WHERE SURVEY_ID = 1 AND KPI_ID = 1;

END;
```

This is the error I am receiving:

SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 15, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ;

What do I need to alter in order to get this to work in this example?
Or are there better ways to write the update for table 1, containing a sum from table 2?

Comment: Code looks OK (unless GROUP BY causes two or more values to be inserted into a scalar variable). **Maybe** you're missing a slash to terminate the PL/SQL anonymous block. Put it into a line that follows the final END and try again.

Comment: The value generated by the query with the GROUP BY statement returns a single result (the number 3). I tried adding a slash, but it returns the same error to me as described in the original post unfortunately.

Comment: Which tool do you use to run that code?

Comment: Running through DBeaver, connected to the Oracle DB where it needs to be executed.

Comment: I did a random test and removed the Update statement and kept the rest (including just the regular END; to end the query/ anonymous block). It runs that section without issue, so somehow adding the update statement will cause the error to occur it seems

Comment: I don't use dBeaver, but Googled a little bit. Try to select the whole PL/SQL block and then execute it.

Comment: I tried both just executing the full script or selecting everything & running the query. Same result.

Comment: No idea, then. I believe code you wrote is OK and would work in e.g. Oracle SQL Developer. If you have it, try. If not, see whether you can download & install it (it is free).

Comment: I will see if we can do that, but I'm unsure if our client would allow a tool change. I may revert to using subqueries in the update statements instead of using variables, I think that may also work even though it isn't as neat in the code.

Comment: One more idea: what happens if you remove all empty lines, then select "all", and then run that code?

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: Too bad ... sorry, I wouldn't know, then. I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: Thank you for you ideas! I will keep on trying to see if I can get it to work in a different way

Comment: Good luck, by all means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing obviously wrong with your code.  But why not just use a correlated subquery and dispense with the variable -- and the PL/SQL?

```
UPDATE table1 t1
    SET CY_VALUE = (SELECT SUM(t2.Column1 + t2.Column2)
                    FROM table2 t2
                    WHERE t2.survey_ID = t1.survey_ID AND
                          t2.Active_Flag = 1
                   )
    WHERE SURVEY_ID = 1 AND KPI_ID = 1;
```

Although not related to your error, the `GROUP BY` in the first query is also misleading.  An aggregate query with a `GROUP BY` can return any number of rows -- including `0`.  Instead, just lead out the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(Column1 + Column2) 
INTO v_var1
FROM table2
WHERE survey_ID = 1 AND Active_Flag = 1;
```

The `WHERE` clause filters down to the `survery_ID` you want and without the `GROUP BY` this query always returns exactly one row.

Comment: I did end up changing my update statement to use correlated subqueries as the variables weren't really needed indeed. I still don't know why it doesn't return results in the method using variables, but it works as intended in its current design. Thank you for the explanation as well!